# Segue to a UITableViewController with custom init

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, initialization

I have a simple push segue that goes from one UITableViewController to another. At the time of initing the other UITableViewController, I want to pass an id that will be used to perform an sqlite query and populate the table. I could use a public property and reload the table in a custom setter, but the design seems better if it is done on initing. After searching around for quite a while I haven't been able to find any clear examples. I have a seen a mentions of `initWithCoder` and `initWithFrame` but they haven't been clear enough to connect it to what I am trying to do.

Here is what the segue looks like from the first table:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowFlashcards"]) {
        //pass variable to custom init somewhere around here?
        FlashcardsTableViewController *flashcardsTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    }
}
```

Here is what the custom init looks like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *listId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *flashcards;

- (id)initWithListId:(NSNumber *)listId {
    self = [super init];
    if (self ) {
        self.listId = listId;
        Database *db = [[Database alloc] init];
        self.flashcards = [db getWordsFromList:[listId integerValue]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-thinking this, and coming to some wrong conclusions.

Adding a property to the destination VC (view controller) and setting it in prepareForSegue is exactly what you want to do.

You can't use a custom init in this situation. Invoking the segue allocates and initializes the destination VC (actually, I believe it is created using the initWithCoder method.) The destination VC's view won't have been loaded yet when prepareForSegue is called, so you can set properties and they will be set up by the time the destination VC's viewDidLoad method gets called.

@AJHacker's answer shows how to give the destination VC a pointer to the source VC, which is useful when the destination needs to be able to send data back.

Comment: I think you are right. Anyway, just reloading the table data in the custom setter works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a property that contains a reference of the first view into the second view. For example:

```
@interface AutoRenewDrop
@property(weak, nonatomic) AddR *callerView;
@end
```

And then in the 'done' method of the second view you can just update the variables in the caller view like so:

```
-(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
callerView.renewDate.text = transferData;
}
```

Of course when you initiate the second view you will have to set the reference, like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Check Mark Segue"])
      {
        NSLog(@"Transfering Data");
    AutoRenewDrop *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.transferData = self.renewDate.text;
    controller.callerView = self; //Here, you are passing the reference to this View
  }
}
```

Hope that helps